# Not able to select last of two identical items in Listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, listboxitem

I have a listbox that holds a members list, but if I add two names that are identical and then try to select the last one it automatically selects the first of the two matched list items.
How can I prevent this from happening without removing the AutoPostBack?

Here is my listbox element in my .aspx website:

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="lbxList" runat="server" Rows="10" SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbxList_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
```

And here is the code behind for the Listbox:

```
protected void lbxList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //Enable delete button if an item is selected
      if (lbxList.SelectedIndex >= 0)
      {
         btnDelete.Enabled = true;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Is it selecting the first of the two matched list items, or is it selecting the first item in the ListBox (i.e. index 0) regardless of what item you choose? My guess is you are binding the list on every PostBack, thus resetting the SelectedIndex to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is add items to your list with different values, they can have same `Text`, but they should have different `Value`

use this line to add Items

```
lbxList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Text", "Value"));
```